# ObjectAnimator scaleX scaleY custom button onClick

Tags: android, animation, button, onclick, scale

I have a circle custom button and try to make scale animation from 0 to 1.5

My code for animation:

```
    AnimatorSet mSet = new AnimatorSet();    

    ObjectAnimator maxX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "scaleX", 0.0f, 1.5f);
    ObjectAnimator maxY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "scaleY", 0.0f, 1.5f);

    mSet.playTogether(maxX, maxY);
    mSet.setDuration(30000);
    mSet.start();
```

Animation works fine, but with one problem, event onClick fire only when button will receive some size.

Can I fire onClick even with small size of button? Or it's impossible?

Comment: yeah ,it should work when the button is small.

Comment: and when I use ScaleAnimation onClick called correct, even with very small button

Comment: it's because ScaleAnimation doesn't change size of button, only representation